# Use of unresolved identifier 'Map' SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am following the [official tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views) for SwiftUI and have run into the error message 'Use of unresolved identifier 'Map'. Even when I copy and and paste the code from the tutorial, it is still giving me the error. I have looked at a few solutions for similar issues and can't seem to find anything that will work. Code below.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: View {
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.011_286, longitude: -116.166_868),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
    )

    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
    }
    }

    struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}
```

I apologise if this is really obvious - but I'm new to Swift/SwiftUI, and can't see where the issue is coming from. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Map` is available since Xcode 12 / iOS 14.0. Maybe you use earlier deployment target or env.

Comment: Map is available from iOS14 onwards only from documentation:
// Available when SwiftUI is imported with MapKit
@available(iOS 14.0, tvOS 14.0, macOS 11.0, watchOS 7.0, *)
public struct Map<Content> : View where Content : View {

Answer (score 2):

I also got into trouble in this case.
So, I make View method using **UIViewRepresentable** with 2 methods: 'makeUIView' and 'updateUIView'.

**MapView**

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapViewUI: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
         MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: 2.6540427, longitude: 98.8932576)
            let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2.0, longitudeDelta: 2.0)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
            view.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And, You can call your View looks like this

```
struct MapPageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapViewUI()
                .frame(height: 300)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works - after some battling - but for Joshua Tree, the coords should be:
                latitude: 33.8734, longitude: -115.9010)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is related to import MapKit. Because Map is defined in MapKit. Please verify if you are able to import MapKit properly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found a better code sample here:

https://github.com/cheukchuen/swiftui-landmarks/blob/main/Landmarks/Views/Helpers/MapView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: View {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion()

    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
            .onAppear {
                setRegion(coordinate)
            }
    }

    private func setRegion(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        region = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: coordinate,
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
        )
    }
}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.011_286, longitude: -116.166_868))
    }
}
```

It replaces "initialPosition" from the tutorial with "coordinateRegion" (which you also found), and adds .onAppear.

When you use this view later, make sure to pass in the coordinate argument (which is where the tutorial is headed anyway). Hope this helps.