# Map is unresolved identifier

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, swiftui, mapkit

I'm following the SwiftUI tutorial.
When i got to the part with Map from MapKit XCode shows the use of unresolved identifier 'Map'.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: View {
    
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(

        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.011_286, longitude: -116.166_868),

        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)

    )
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
    }
}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been asked before, Map is relatively new so make sure the target is set to iOS 14.0 at least. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65438443/use-of-unresolved-identifier-map-swiftui)

Comment: Thanks for the help, that did it.